# Clean stock Windows eating up 21 Gb of ram

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

I bought a new PC that has 40gb of ram, and just installed a clean windows on it, with only chrome and few tabs open my **ram usage is 21 GB !** the numbers in task manager don't add up to even 30% of this usage, chrome is only using 1gb of ram and the other processes are using less. I searched and followed many tutorials to track **the problem that seems to be in the paged pool**, I used poolmon.exe and I found the most 2 using paged pool memory are MmSt and Ntff which are related to windows file management and ntfs filesystem, most tutorials and answers suggest that high usage is because of a faulty driver or something similar and updating or removing it fixes the issue. what should I do knowing that the problem is from windows itself ? remove windows ?

[image: ram usage]

And here is the output of poolmon.exe :

[image]

Rammap output:
[image]

Comment: Is this after a clean reboot? Not shutdown and restart, an actual reboot.

Comment: The OS simply doesn't care about 'saving RAM' when it has RAM to spare. If it sits idle it's just wasted. You bought all the RAM, let it be used. It speeds your machine up. Here I have 64GB, typically, after a couple of days' usage, it "using" maybe 50 of that. That's exactly what it's supposed to do. No pressure, no worry. Not even any swap used yet.

Comment: Can you go into the Resource Monitor (linked at the bottom of task manager in your screenshot) select the Memory tab and then sort by the "Commit" column (click on the header). Would be good to see what is in there.

Comment: @Mokubai I went to resource monitor and it is the same as the task manager, no processes are eating ram, the process using most ram is perfmon which is the process of resource monitor itself, it is using 890mb. the OS is the guy using the ram not the programs, I am 100% sure of that.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you for sharing your experience, I have one more question, after days or weeks of usage, ram used by windows won't hold other processes back ? if windows is using 50gb, can other programs use as much ram as they need ? I need to process large data so I may need every bit of ram I can use, will windows let programs freely use of the ram it is holding ? have you ran into any performance issues ? maybe try running 3 large games or programs when windows is holding 50gb of ram and see what happens.

Comment: As soon as something else needs it more, it will be instantly handed back - unless you have a true memory leak, but that can be sometimes difficult to prove. Empirically, if all apps hand back memory when needed, then there is no leak. Proving the definitions of 'need' & 'hand back' is the tough bit. Just because an app *uses* memory does not necessarily imply it *leaks*. In short, don't ever let it bother you unless it actually happens.

Comment: I hate to disagree with everyone, but my system has been up for 6 days, and my paged pool looks nothing like the authors.  I have nearly 50 GB out of 64 GB.  However, Chrome is using 2 GB out of that 14 GB, that is being used.  The author has something going on that should be identified.  I would need a screenshot of RAMMap to diagnose honestly.

Comment: the ram usage has decreased a bit from what it was in the screenshots, after I put the PC to sleep for like 8 or 10 hours. the screenshots are of around 10 hours ago, but it is still high. in task manager : | Paged pool now : 7.8 Gb | Non-paged pool : 2.4 Gb | and total ram usage is 18 Gb. Shutting down or restarting makes ram usage start low and will pile up with time. So guys if this is normal tell me, this will give me a peace of mind. If not, tell me what steps I need to take to identify the issue or fix it.

Comment: The paged and nonpaged pools are surprisingly large and could be related to your large "mapped file". Mine are currently around 500MB each. I'm not too familiar with debugging that side of windows, but we have some guides in the answers to this search https://superuser.com/search?q=paged+pool

Comment: @Mokubai I went through many answers and microsoft documentation, this is from where I got the poolmon tool to identify which tags are using pool memory, all the solutions are about faulty drivers leaking memory.

Comment: in my case it is windows itself using the memory, following what they all say "use poolmon.exe to identify the tag using pool memory" I found that windows is the one using the memory, the screenshot I attached makes that clear, MmSt and Ntff are windows tags using most of my Ram, the solutions I see everywhere "identify the driver or program leaking memory and kill it or update it" don't apply here

Comment: Yeah, those page pool tags give a lot of "update everything" advice. Specifically https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/getting-to-know-the-mmst-pool-tag/ba-p/374971 says to  "Apply the latest hotfixes for core OS files to fix known issues." and suggests that this is most commonly experienced on heavy file-server or exchange server systems. If this is  a heavy load file server then it might just be normal. Also https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/poolmon-examples has some more interesting usage of poolmon that might help narrow it down.

Comment: @Ramhound just seen your comment late but I agree with you, this is not the "cache" hence my disagreement with harry on his answer below. There is some information I found in my last comment that suggests that this might be "normal" on systems with absolutely huge numbers of files that can cause the MFT to bloat, or on systems with heavy disk usage meaning that the OS cannot flush data out fast enough causing internal write buffers (not cache) to bloat. It is definitely something to investigate and I think more information on the machine and its use cases might be needed to establish "normal".

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the cache memory of Windows, which is typically 50% of the RAM.

This memory is not reserved, and will be used by Windows for other uses,
if required.

This is standard behavior in most operating systems, not only in Windows.

So don't worry - your memory is still there and available for use.

This is a classical situation that comes up all the time on our site: Large memory seems to be used, but looking at the processes there is no explanation. It is used by Windows, certainly, and the output from poolmon is open to various interpretations. The best answer is: If you are not running out of memory, then everything is working correctly. Keep an eye on the used memory figures and see if they increase appreciably without you doing anything to cause it. If it doesn't happen, then no point in worrying.

In addition, you are using Windows Server, which is also a File Server
for the local network. As such, it will tend to keep more data in RAM,
to better serve the local network. The fact that in your case the
network is made up of only your computer will not change its behavior.

Comment: So typically windows will always be using 20Gb of ram on a 40Gb system ? and if other processes need the ram it will free it ? I am afraid that I will run out of ram because after restarting ram usage is low and then it is gradually increasing, after 6 hours of use it reached 21Gb then I shut it down. Won't it go beyond that if I leave my workstation working for 3 days or a week ? or fill the whole 40 gigs and leave me with a ram shortage ?

Comment: It's not really "using" the memory and it's still still available to be allocated for programs, in case that the programs gobble up the other 20 GB and still need more. In situations where the cache memory is much reduced, repeated disk accesses could be degraded, as there is less chance of finding disk data already in memory, so the data needs to be read again from the disk.

Comment: The cache shows very differently and is the right hand very pale block beside the 20GB that is used. sure the cached is the *other* 20GB but it is not the "main" 20GB. Hover over the blocks shown under "Memory composition" and you get a description of each block, the largest 20GB used block will show "used by processes, drivers and the operating system", the block to the right will show "Standby: contains cached data and code not actively in use" you are looking at the wrong block and they *do* have a problem of some kind here

Comment: @Mokubai: I don't get your remark. Where do you see "Memory composition" and where do you hover. On my computer I also have a large number for used memory, but no memory leak.

Comment: @ElyesLounissi: To check if you have a memory leak in any of your programs, go in Task Manager to the Details tab, right-click on any header, Select columns, add "Memory (active private working set)", click OK, then click on the header to sort by descending order.

Comment: @harrymc First picture, right hand side, second graph. Hover over those areas. Just because you don't have a memory leak doesn't automatically mean that "caching" is to blame. Sure it not being used is waste, but cache is not included in "used" memory in Windows.

Comment: @Mokubai: That information is not very informative. It's also very large on my computer.

Comment: But it is informative in telling you what is using memory: not the cache. That is a whole other 16GB of RAM to the right of "used" memory. A program might be doing its own caching, and Chrome is an utter nightmare from a memory management perspective with its "gotta use em all" attitude, but that is something very different from the Windows cache.

Comment: guys don't fight please and there is no need for downvoting people that are trying to help, any help is welcome, I opened details tab in task manager and the process using most memory is one of chrome's processes and it is using only 330Mb, the operating system is using a lot of memory I guess not programs

Comment: all of chrome's processes add up to only 1.2 gb

Comment: The downvote is because the answer is factually incorrect. If it were corrected then the downvote would be removed. Your 20GB used does not include the cache, plain and simple. If you include the cache then you are using around 37GB of RAM.

Comment: Okay, then please tell me who is using my 21gb of ram, I am only running chrome and of course there are some background processes, by far they won't be using more than 5gb, I want to understand who is using the rest ?
I am on a thinkpad p50 with updated drivers, windows 10 server ltsc updated, and nothing installed except a couple of programs that are not currently running

Comment: and poolmon shows that pool memory usage is very high and that it is mostly used by windows processes, why, how ? is this normal ?

Comment: This is a classical situation that comes up all the time on our site: Large memory seems to be used, but looking at the processes there is no explanation. It is used by Windows, certainly, and the output from poolmon is open to various interpretations. The best answer is: If you are not running out of memory, then everything is working correctly. Keep an eye on the used memory figures and see if they increase appreciably without you doing anything to cause it. If it doesn't happen, then no point in worrying.

Comment: also attempting to help is really appreciated, everyone makes mistakes, and maybe @harrymc is partially or totally correct, I have no knowledge in windows specific behavior.

Comment: @harrymc okay, I will keep an eye on task manager every now and then, and if I run out of memory (or come close to running out of memory) I will update this post.

Comment: @harrymc That statement I will not argue with at all. Your answer as it is currently phrased, and where it places the blame on "the cache memory of Windows" and states "This memory is not reserved" (which is why it shows as "standby") is where my problem is. The memory they have a problem with (20GB) is clearly under the "reserved" memory block.

Comment: @Mokubai: The data is divided into 2 parts: Compressed or not. The Compressed is usually minimal if there is no memory eating problem. The rest is **everything**, including the cache, the 1.2 GB taken by Chrome etc. etc. A large number is not necessarily indicative of a problem, if there are active programs, as Windows doesn't swap out disk data if there is no need.

Comment: guys, is there a way to know if this behavior is normal or not ? I am setting up a workstation for processing large data and big numbers of parallelized processes, I will have it running for weeks or months. I would really appreciate any help, I need to set things up once and then leave it running

Comment: I am literally using windows 10 server ltsc because of its smaller memory footprint and better stability and no feature updates (that can break things), this doesn't seem like a small memory footprint xD

Comment: @ElyesLounissi It is not 100% normal but not necessarily 100% bad either and I've asked for more information under your question.